# Static - Non-Static methods in Java

Tags: java, database, parsing, static

I got a noob question concerning Static vs. Non-Static Methods. 
In this example I parse Data out and want to write it to my DB. I was doing fine as long as I declared the method getData() static. But now when im invoking Database.insert(x,y,z) - the static-non static error comes into play. I just can't wrap my thoughts around the problem how to solve this issue.

Can anyone explain to me, how I can write those variables into my DB? your help is highly valued and will help me advance in java.

**EDIT:**

Error message saying:

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method insert(String, String, String, String) from the type Database
```

Code:

```
package org.jsoup.examples;

import java.io.*;   

import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.nodes.*;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Example program to list links from a URL.
 */
public class parseEasy {

     String companyName = "Platzhalter";
        String jobTitle = "Platzhalter";
        String location = "Platzhalter";
        String timeAdded = "Platzhalter";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        Database connect = new Database();
        connect.OpenConnectionDB();
        getData();

        connect.closeConnectionDB();


    }

    // FIRMENNAME
    public static void getData() throws IOException 
    {

        int count = 0;
        Document document = Jsoup.parse(new File("C:/Talend/workspace/WEBCRAWLER/output/keywords_SOA.txt"), "utf-8");
        Elements elements = document.select(".joblisting");
        for (Element element : elements) 
        {
            // Counter for Number of Elements returned
            count++;

            // Parse Data into Elements
            Elements jobTitleElement = element.select(".job_title span");
            Elements companyNameElement = element.select(".company_name span[itemprop=name]");
            Elements locationElement = element.select(".locality span[itemprop=addressLocality]");
            Elements dateElement = element.select(".job_date_added [datetime]");

            // Strip Data from unnecessary tags
            String companyName = companyNameElement.text();
            String jobTitle = jobTitleElement.text();
            String location = locationElement.text();
            String timeAdded = dateElement.text();

            Database.insert(companyName, jobTitle, timeAdded, location);


            // Test output
            System.out.println("Firma:\t"+ companyName + "\t" + jobTitle + "\t in:\t" + location + " \t Erstellt am \t" + timeAdded + "\t. Eintrag Nummer:\t" + count);

        }


    }

    /* public void writeDB(String a,String b,String c,String d){
        Database.insert(a, b, c, d);

    }


    String getcompanyName(){
        return companyName;     
    }

    String getjobTitle(){
        return jobTitle; }

    String gettimeAdded(){
        return timeAdded; }

    String getlocation(){
        return location; }
    */
  }
```

Comment: What exactly does the error message say? We don't want to dig through your wall of code.

Comment: This is extensively documented in the official docs, and also described at lenght in hundreds of java tutorials and books. Do some reading and figure it out by yourself.

Comment: Where does `Database` come from?

Comment: You have to make the `connect` variable a `static` member of your class, rather than a local variable, and call `connect.insert`, rather than `Database.insert`, as you are inserting into this particular database. `insert` is a non-static method of `Database`, as inserting without indicating a particular database to insert into probably does not make sense. Btw, shouldn't you insert into a database *table*? And why are `companyName` etc. non-static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Static` and `Non-Static` also have 2, perhaps better names.

`Static` is also known as `Class-Level`, and `Non-Static` is `Instance-Level`

Example:

```
class SomeClass {
    static void staticPrint() {
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^ static
        System.out.println("Hello from static");
    }

    void instancePrint() {
//  ^^^^ not static
        System.out.println("Hello from non-static");
    }
}
```

So here's where these two types of methods differ:

```
SomeClass obj = new SomeClass();

SomeClass.staticPrint(); // prints "Hello from static"
SomeClass.instancePrint(); // throws an error

obj.staticPrint(); // throws an error
obj.instancePrint(); // prints "Hello from non-static"
```

That's it. That's the difference between static and non-static

One works directly from the class, the other works from the object you create when you `new` it